# Have a question about PTR when used in a CALL instruction when using MASM

Tags: masm

I have not seen in MASM's documentation information about PTR register as used in this example:

```
.486

.Model flat,stdcall

label1 typedef ptr proc

.data

   mydata db 20h

.code

main proc

   call label1 ptr esi

main endp

end
```

Where do I find information on the CALL instruction with using PTR register?

Answer (score 0):

`PTR` is not a register. `PTR` is a MASM syntax element, shorthand for "pointer" and is a kind of cast operator. So for example `mov DWORD PTR [esi], 0` means "treat the address `esi` points to as DWORD (32 bit), and copy a zero there", so this clears 4 bytes. In contrast, `mov BYTE PTR [esi], 0` means to just clear 1 byte.

In your example, `label1` is defined to represent the type "pointer to procedure". In the `CALL` instruction, `PTR` is used to tell the assembler that the address `esi` points to has the type "procedure". The CALL intstruction calls the procedure, whose address is stored in `ESI`.

As far as I know, this cast is useless in this example, because there is no ambiguity to be resolved by the cast: `CALL` with a 32 bit register operand is always an indirect near call, taking the address to be called from the 32-bit register.

Comment: Thank you for the information on PTR. I did not see any documentation in masm on PTR being after the CALL instruction. And I did not see any examples of PTR with a non-bracketed register after it. Where do I find the information on those?

Comment: @StillLearning Search the MASM 6.1 Documentation pdf file.